# Why won't my 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G auto-focus on my Nikon D3200?

Tags: lens, nikon, autofocus, troubleshooting

I got an used D3200 and I've been using it a prime 50mm 1.8D with no issue whatsoever. Yesterday I got my 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G which I also bought 2nd handed on ebay and I simply cant focus anything. I've changed various settings regarding AF but nothing works. Is something wrong with my camera / lens or I am just missing the obvious?

Comment: Which lens model is it exactly? What _does_ it do? Does it _attempt_ autofocus but fail, or does nothing happen? On the "something obvious" front, have you flipped the AF / MF switch on the lens barrel?

Comment: It doesnt have that switch. And simply nothing happens.
http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-p_dx_18-55mmf_35-56g/index.htm

I think I already found my awnser... My camera simply isn't compatible >.> 
Thats what you get when you don't double check stuff..

Comment: mine is brand new and not focusing

Comment: @mary did you read the answer?  Is yours an AF-P model of the lens?  If so the answer below will explain why it won't focus.  Otherwise, please ask a new question for your specific problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you have purchased the AF-P model of that lens. These lenses use a stepper motor, and for whatever reason are only compatible with the D3300 and newer — not your D3200. (Presumably, the new motors need a more complex interaction that the older models just aren't prepared for.) You'll need to look for an AF-S model — there are four of them:

- AF-S DX Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G ED (2005)
- AF-S DX Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G ED II (2006)
- AF-S DX Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G VR (2007)
- AF-S DX Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G VR II (2014)

The latter two add VR, and you can read more about the differences at [What is the difference between these two 18-55mm kit lens options for the Nikon D3100?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15630/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-18-55mm-kit-lens-options-for-the-nikon)

*But*, unless someone is basically giving one away, I'm not sure I'd recommend it. Personally, I'd first look at the AF-S DX Nikkor 35mm f/1.8G to complement your 50mm prime, but if you're really feeling you need a wide-normal zoom, I'd instead look at saving up a bit more for something like the [Sigma 17-50mm F2.8 EX DC](http://www.imaging-resource.com/lenses/sigma/17-50mm-f2.8-ex-dc-os-hsm/review/) — this will cover about the same range, but let in more light and give moderately better technical image quality.

Comment: Yeah thanks for your advice ... I totally should've checked before making the purchase ... How dumb of me... Oh well .. it was cheap though, 30€ xD

I will look up for that sigma, will see what i can find out :)

Comment: If you want a lens with a zoom ring that turns the same direction as Nikon's own lenses do, get the Tamron SP 17-50mm f/2.8 Di II instead of the Sigma (which turns in the "Canon" direction). Otherwise you're going to get used to turning the zoom ring the opposite way and any Nikon zoom lenses you eventually pick up will feel "wrong" to you!